# Combine function in SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml

Hey, im very new to SML and programming alltogether, i want to write a function that combine within lists, such that
[x1,x2,x3,x4,...] = [(x1,x2),(x3,x4),...] Any hints or help for me to go in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the problem it becomes apparent that we will probably want to process the input two items at a time.

So let's look at what we want to do with each pair: If x1 and x2 are the items we're currently looking at, we want to put the pair `(x1, x2)` into the list we're creating. If `xs` is the list of items that come after `x1` and `x2`, we want the pair `(x1, x2)` to be followed by the result of "combining" xs. So we can write our combine function as:

```
fun combineWithin (x1::x2::xs) = (x1, x2)::(combineWithin xs)
```

However this definition is not yet complete. We're only looking at the case where `xs` has at least two items. So we need to ask ourself what we want to do in the other two cases.

For the empty list it's easy: The result of combining the empty list, is the empty list.

For a list with only one item we can either also return the empty list, or raise an error (or possibly pair the one item with itself). In other words: we need to decide whether `combineWithin [1,2,3]` should return `[(1,2)]` or `[(1,2), (3,3)]` or throw an error.

If we decide we want the former, our function becomes:

```
fun combineWithin (x1::x2::xs) = (x1, x2)::(combineWithin xs)
  | combineWithin _ = []
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let rec pairs = function
| [] -> []
| [x] -> []
| x1::x2::rest -> (x1, x2)::(pairs rest)
```

Comment: That is ocaml syntax, not sml.